# Running an Rscript.exe shortcut on Windows 8

Tags: r, rscript

I have a myfile.R that I am trying source using the shortcut Rscript.exe, and I have the target line in the properties of the Rscript.exe setup as

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" --e 'source(myfile.R)'
```

I have also tried:

```
 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" --e myfile.R
 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" --vanilla myfile.R
 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" myfile.R
 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" "myfile.R"
```

and nothing has worked thus far.

In the start in line of the properties of Rscript.exe i have:

```
"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\rfile"
```

which is the file that myfile.R is in.

When I source that file in R studio it functions great and writes the information to MS Access using the RODBC package just as I hoped, but trying to get the same functionality with the Rscript.exe has eluded me.

I suspect I am missing some kind of command after the .exe or I am missing some code at the begging of myfile.R that will allow it to function with Rscript.exe.

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to run it from a command (DOS) window? For instance by `cd`ing into the script's directory and running `"...\Rscript.exe" myfile.R`?

Comment: I tried that last night for the first time, but RODBC wont connect correctly. I am starting to wonder if it is an issue using RODBC.

Comment: Yup, might well be a librairies issue, where RStudio "knows" where to look for the packages but R run from RScript.exe doesn't.

Comment: Ok, after a bit more tinkering I realized it was a 32bit vs 64bit issue. I should have realized that because it wasn't the first time RODBC didn't work for me with 64bit R. Thanks for the help Dominic.